# Reusing user-defined function pointer type to declare a function

Tags: c++, function-pointers, c++17

I am trying to find a way to declare a function by re-using a previously declared function pointer type, as it would allow me to avoid duplication in code (very useful when you have to declare a lot of functions with identical signatures). In other words, I would like to do something like this:

```
//Declare re-usable function pointer type
using TFunctionAddr = int(*)(int arg0);
//And now, instead of duplicating a function signature like so:
int FunctionUgly(int arg0)
{
  return arg0 + 1;
}
//I would like to use TFunctionAddr to somehow declare a new function
//without reiterating its return type and formal argument list
SomeMagicSyntaxHere(TFunctionAddr, FunctionNeat)
{
  return arg0 + 1;
}
//Here "SomeMagicSyntax()" is a pseudo-code, not an actual language construct
```

Question: is it at all possible in C/C++ and if yes, what should that be that "magic syntax"?

Notice that in this snippet I am not using function pointers to call anything yet, this happens later in the code and is irrelevant to the question at hand.

I am open for suggestions that require any level of C++ standard support, including C++17 and standard library  header facilities, but obviously more bare-bone solutions would be more preferable.

Comment: I think it is possible to _declare_ said function without reiterating its return type and formal argument list, but it is not possible to _define_ the function without reiterating.

Comment: Are you looking for [decltype](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype)?